# check number range python

Tags: python, api, range

I wrote python script where im connecing to api, entering number and get responce from it

```
import requests
import re
while True:
    number1 = input("nomeri ")
    num = "number"
    params = {}
    params[num]= number1
    var = requests.post('api', data = params)
    info = str(var.text)

    m = re.search('"info":{"name":\"(.+?)\"}}', info)
    if m:
      found = m.group(1)
      var = u"{}".format(found)
      text = open("text.txt", 'a')
      text.write(number1)
      print(var )
    else:
      print("not found")
```

now i want to reorginize it, and check number range from 000000 to 999999 and if it found write it to text file.range will be 0000009, 000090,000091 etc, how can i generate it?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you need at the end? You need ***a new code block or edit something you've made***? Also where is the number range you mentioned comming from?

Comment: in this code im entering number as input, i need to incriment number from 000000 to 999999 and send it as input

Comment: i researched and format string was one but no luck

Comment: main question is how generate six digit number incriment in python

Comment: added an answer to pass the values with 6 digits using `zfill()` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54637366/2970272

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a always six digits you could make your number as a string and use `zfill()` to specify how many digits you want. For example:

```
# the 1000000 instead of 999999 otherwise it would print/send as far as 999998
for i in range(0, 1000000):       


    # first converting the `i` to string to be able to use it's '.zfill' function
    print(str(i).zfill(6))
```

So ***you'd only have to adjust this** `for loop` with range that ***instead of printing***, `passing the input to your API`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and the comments correctly, your code works, but you want to have it in a loop to make a lot of requests.

To format a number as a string with leading zeros you can use `{:06d}.format(number)`.

I also suggest adding to a list or dict and after the loop write to the file, because it could be more efficient that way.

```
import requests
import re
result_dict = {}

# check numbers from 0 to 999.999
for i in range(10**6):
    params = {
        'number': '{:06d}'.format(i),    # a string, the number with leading zeros
    }
    resp = requests.post('api', data=params)

    m = re.search('"info":{"name":\"(.+?)\"}}', str(resp.text))
    if m:
        found_element = u"{}".format(m.group(1))
    else:
        found_element = None
    result_dict[i] = found_element

with open("text.txt", 'w') as f:
    for k, v in sorted(result_dict.items()):
        if v is not None:
            print('Value for', k, 'is', v)
            f.write('{:06d}\n'.format(k))
        else:
            print('Value for', k, 'was not found')
```